# Vagrant on mac can't chmod -R 777 . for folders

Tags: vagrant

Using Vagrant on mac with virtual box

I try to `sudo chmod -R 777 .' in /vagrant folder, or in the folder project in mac terminal, but in both cases only the files in the sub folders chmod but the folder doesn't chmod.

This cause my code to fail with `permission denied` because it cannot write to any folder.

If I go to a specific folder and do `sudo chmod 777 ' than it is working ok, but I have too many folders to do it manually.

Please help

Comment: What is if you use "-R"? The man page specify only the uppercase "R" in some cases its not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the following file as root: /etc/apache2/envvars

using the command:

sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars

Change the user to vagrant.

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=vagrant
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Add vagrant user to www-data group

```
sudo adduser vagrant www-data
```

Restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This answer save me so much time again ;)